# Ajax not rendering the partial in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Ajax partial is not rendering in my rails application.

I am having an `Article` model. I am trying to add new articles using Ajax

Please find the code below.

**cart.html.erb**

```
<div id="articles">
  <%= render 'showarticles' %>
</div>
```

**cart.js.erb**

```
$('#articles').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('static_pages/showarticles')) %>');
$('.form-control').val('')
```

**routes.rb**

```
match 'cart/:id', to: 'static_pages#cart', via: [:get, :post]
```

**_showarticles.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @article, :remote => true do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :name, :class => "form-control" %>
<% end %>    
<% @art.each do |a| %>
<%= a.name %>
<% end %>
```

**static_pages_controller.rb**

```
def cart
  @art = Article.all
  @article = Article.new 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.js
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you triggering the call to the cart action?

Comment: @japed : This is how I triggered the cart action: redirect_to action: 'cart', controller: 'static_pages', id: cart.id

Comment: @japed: I am having a Cart controller. So after creating a Cart it redirects to the Cart page in the Create action of the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding this line to my `routes.rb` file:

```
match 'cart', to: 'static_pages#cart', via: [:get, :post]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

so this

```
<%= form_for @article, :remote => true do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :name, :class => "form-control" %>
<% end %>    
<% @art.each do |a| %>
<%= a.name %>
<% end %>
```

Will go to the articles create method. Which is why your cart.js.erb isn't called.  Either set the url `<%= form_for @article, :url => url_for(:controller => 'static_pages, :action => 'cart', :id => @cart.id), :remote => true do |f| %>` or preferably handle it in the create action of your articles controller